# How to get distinct elements within a python tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I want to get distinct values from tuple list. Let's say we have following tuple list generated from,

```
df_clustering_dupliacteRemove.groupby('cluster').agg(tuple).sum(1).map(natsorted).map(tuple)
```

Output

```
 604                             (GM0051, GM0178, GM0191)
 605                     (GM0134, GM0267, GM0351, GM0615)
 606                             (GM0180, GM0474, GM0512)
 607                             (GM0216, GM0471, GM0586)
 608                             (GM0373, GM0373, GM0373)
```

If you look at the 608 th tupple the elements are the same. I want to make those elements one (get unique/distinct values).

Sample Output I need

```
 604                             (GM0051, GM0178, GM0191)
 605                     (GM0134, GM0267, GM0351, GM0615)
 606                             (GM0180, GM0474, GM0512)
 607                             (GM0216, GM0471, GM0586)
 608                             (GM0373)
```

Comment: You can try converting them to `set` to make it unique and then wrap it again with `tuple` to retain the data type

Comment: Well, I tried, it gives unique tuples. Not the unique values within a tuple.

Comment: post a testable dataframe fragment

Comment: You have tuple of tuples or list of tuples ? You could iterate each tuple and try the method I mentioned earlier @VINURAPERERA

Comment: Well i removed it from the duplicates from initial df_clustering_dupliacteRemove data frame. It was easy. Before performing a groupBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
> myDf

    COL
0   (a, b, c)
1   (d, e, f)
2   (a, a)
3   a
4   (c, c, c)

> result = pd.DataFrame(myDf.apply( lambda x : tuple(set(x[0])), axis=1))
> result

0
0   (a, b, c)
1   (f, e, d)
2   (a,)
3   (a,)
4   (c,)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, I used sets in order to simplify a tuple :)

```
def simplify_tuple(t):
    return tuple({i for i in t})

tuple_ = (1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
print(simplify_tuple(tuple_))
# (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do set of tuple to get unique values from each tuple.

```
In [1]: data = [('GM0051', 'GM0178', 'GM0191'),('GM0134', 'GM0267', 'GM0351', 'GM0615'),('GM0180', 'GM0474', 'GM0512'),('GM0216', 'GM0471', 'GM0586'),('GM0373', 'GM0373', 'GM0373')]
In [2]: [tuple(set(d)) for d in data]
Out[2]: 
    [('GM0051', 'GM0191', 'GM0178'),
    ('GM0267', 'GM0134', 'GM0351', 'GM0615'),
    ('GM0474', 'GM0512', 'GM0180'),
    ('GM0216', 'GM0471', 'GM0586'),
    ('GM0373',)]
```